# Systemd ProtectHome & Allowing access to specific home directory

Tags: systemd

I'm having trouble with a systemd service with the following definition:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/testuser/testdir
User=testuser
Group=testuser
ProtectHome=true

...
```

Until I've updated my packages a couple of days ago, this worked fine.
However right now with ProtectHome set to true, the service gets a permission denied when it's trying to access the home directory of the user it's running under.

Is this intended (i.e. ProtectHome denies access to every home directory, even your own)?
If yes, is there any way to whitelist the specific directory under home? Adding it to ReadWriteDirectories doesn't seem to work.
Or should I rather move the directory for the service away from home?

Thanks for your help

Tobi

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page of systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ProtectHome=) discussing `ProtectHome=`:

> If true, the directories /home/, /root, and /run/user are made inaccessible and empty for processes invoked by this unit.

You should expect the home directory to be inaccessible to the service, even if it is running as the user who owns the directory.

I don’t believe this behavior has changed recently, so I don’t know why it would have worked before.  Perhaps you added the setting but didn’t daemon-reload?