# SSH not possible when using fish (installed through Nix) as shell

Tags: fedora, openssh, selinux, nix

Using the **nix** package manager, I've installed **fish** for my login shell. I've added the shell to **/etc/shells**:

```
$ bat /etc/shells | grep --color=auto fish
/home/ajgringo619/.nix-profile/bin/fish
```

This works on all of my systems - Debian, Fedora, Gentoo, Ubuntu, openSUSE. The problem is with **Fedora** (using v37) and SSH connections. While my other systems all work, the Fedora system claims that the login shell does not exist:

```
$ which fish
/home/ajgringo619/.nix-profile/bin/fish
$ journalctl -fu sshd.service 
Dec 26 11:30:50 fedora sshd[977]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Dec 26 11:30:50 fedora sshd[977]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Dec 26 11:30:50 fedora systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Dec 26 11:30:50 fedora systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Dec 26 11:31:46 fedora-cin sshd[2030]: User ajgringo619 not allowed because shell /home/ajgringo619/.nix-profile/bin/fish does not exist
Dec 26 11:31:57 fedora-cin sshd[2030]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.122.1  user=ajgringo619
Dec 26 11:32:00 fedora-cin sshd[2030]: Failed password for invalid user ajgringo619 from 192.168.122.1 port 39226 ssh2
Dec 26 11:32:11 fedora-cin sshd[2030]: Connection closed by invalid user ajgringo619 192.168.122.1 port 39226 [preauth]
```

In looking at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, nothing has been changed since install. Any ideas what **Fedora** is doing that the other are not? This did not happen when I had **fish** installed via **dnf**.

UPDATE #1: this is an selinux issue. Since changing selinux to "permissive", this issue is resolved. However, I'd really like to edit what selinux has done so I can leave the default settings as is.

Comment: [`ProtectHome`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684074/108618)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - it's an selinux issue. I just changed it to "permissive" and it works now; not an ideal solution, but a solution nonetheless.

Comment: What is the command `bat`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: OP fixed it them self, and did not leave an answer.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor - sorry about that. Go ahead and close, although I don't really like the fix (more of a workaround).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor - 'bat' is a 'cat' clone

Comment: @ajgringo619 no need for `bat`s or `cat`s you can do `< /etc/shells grep --color=auto fish`

Answer (score 0):

`fish` installed via `dnf` is installed in `/usr/bin/` and has the following SELinux context:

```
$ ls -laZ $(which fish)
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root system_u:object_r:shell_exec_t:s0 1721760 Jan 31 15:35 /usr/bin/fish
```

Note `shell_exec_t`! Now, let's install Fish through Nix:

```bash
# Download Nix
$ sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install)

# Source profile
$ . ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh

# Install Fish
$ nix-env -iA nixpkgs.fish
```

Let's check the `fish` binary again:

```bash
$ which fish
/home/edward/.nix-profile/bin/fish

$ ls -laZ $(which fish)
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 edward wheel unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 63 Jan  1  1970 /home/edward/.nix-profile/bin/fish -> /nix/store/4mh0j2gm92dwin2dx4v6rhhjr01d6q5y-fish-3.6.0/bin/fish
```

You see it has context `default_t` now.

Let's try setting `fish` as my default shell:

```bash
$ sudo usermod -s $(which fish) edward
$ cat /etc/passwd|grep edward
edward:x:1000:10::/home/edward:/home/edward/.nix-profile/bin/fish
```

Alright. Now login through SSH as `edward`, it won't work, just like you said. Let's check the SELinux AVC denial logs:

```bash
$ sudo ausearch -ts recent -m avc -i
----
type=AVC msg=audit(02/17/2023 20:01:31.125:440) : avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2642 comm=sshd name=profile dev="dm-0" ino=839852 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
```

So, `sshd`, running with the `sshd_t` context, isn't allowed to access the file at inode 839852. What file?

```
$ sudo find / -xdev -inum 839852
/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/edward/profile
```

This is the point you should conclude that Nix doesn't work with SELinux enabled, because everything under `/nix` is unlabeled.

Of course, you could write your own policy file. That'll only work for this particular use case: logging in through SSH using Fish as shell in a Nix environment.

First: disable SELinux by putting it temporarily in permissive mode:

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

Now do the login thing again, it'll work. Re-enable SELinux:

```
$ sudo setenforce 1
```

Get a policy module for everything that has failed in the meantime. Let's list what failed:

```bash
$ sudo ausearch -m avc -ts recent -c sshd
----
time->Fri Feb 17 20:01:31 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1676660491.125:440): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2642 comm="sshd" name="profile" dev="dm-0" ino=839852 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
----
time->Fri Feb 17 20:09:11 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1676660951.340:455): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2679 comm="sshd" name="profile" dev="dm-0" ino=839852 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=1
----
time->Fri Feb 17 20:09:11 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1676660951.342:456): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=2679 comm="sshd" path="/nix/store/4mh0j2gm92dwin2dx4v6rhhjr01d6q5y-fish-3.6.0/bin/fish" dev="dm-0" ino=839796 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
----
time->Fri Feb 17 20:09:11 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1676660951.825:473): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2681 comm="sshd" name="profile" dev="dm-0" ino=839852 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=1
```

The first line was when we tried to login with SELinux enabled. The last lines are our succesful login.

If you pipe the output above through `audit2allow`, you see that only this is required from a SELinux perspective:

```
#============= sshd_t ==============
allow sshd_t default_t:file getattr;
allow sshd_t default_t:lnk_file read;
```

Almost there. Let's make a module out of it and install it in the running policy.

```bash
$ sudo ausearch -m avc -ts recent -c sshd | audit2allow -M sshd-fish-nix
$ sudo semodule -i sshd-fish-nix.pp
```

You'll now be able to login using SSH with SELinux enabled.